# C++ performance degradation (or code must be improved ?)

Tags: c++, windows

I am developping a simple program that copies the same string into another one in a loop. I use Visual Studio C++ 2019 Community Edition, and the project type is "Command line".

If I run it for 3,42 seconds then the calculated number of copies per second is 130 601 397, but if I run it for 77,97 seconds then the number of copies per second is 47 469 296...

The more time the program is running, the more performance degradation there is...

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <signal.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned long repeats_counter = 0;

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2;

// When CTRL+C (SIGINT), this is executed 
signal_callback_handler(int signum) {
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << "Total execution time " << diff.count() << " s\n";
    unsigned long average_repeats_per_sec = (unsigned long)(repeats_counter / diff.count());
    std::cout << "Number of average repeats per second was " << 
    std::to_string(average_repeats_per_sec) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of average repeats per minute was " << 
    std::to_string(average_repeats_per_sec * 60) << "\n";
    cout << "Number of effective repeats = " << repeats_counter << endl;
    // Terminate program
    exit(signum);
}


int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);

    std::string from_str, to_str;

    cout << "Start copying. CTRL+C to stop." << endl;
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    from_str = "the string to be copied";
    while (true) {
        to_str = from_str;
        repeats_counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your CPU is heating up and being throttled down? We need more details. If you can pin your CPU frequency you'll get more consistent test results.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of details ? How to pin the CPU freq ?

Comment: What hardware are you running this on? Can you monitor CPU speed to ensure it's not being lowered because of thermal throttling?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz   3.19 GHz and 16 GB RAM

Comment: Use Windows Task Manager to observe CPU speed. That 3.2GHz is often a "rated" speed, not how fast it's actually going, especially in a laptop where there are many, different power modes, some of which throttle down aggressively to conserve power. Most Intel-type CPUs will throttle up ("Turbo") until they hit their thermal envelope, at which point they start to slow down to a steady-state that depends on cooling capacity, and in some cases, how much dust is in your fans.

Comment: In TaskMgr, the CPU used is constantly around 28%, Memory used is constantly around 7,7Mb. The "Energy consumption" is "Very high". It is not a laptop but a desktop computer (HP Prodesk 600 G3 MT).

Comment: You should run the same test on other machines and collect more data. There's nothing here that should slow down software-wise, so that means it's likely your hardware.

Comment: I have made other tests yesterday but on a laptop and there is the same behavior... I don't know what to investigate... Could you give me other clues ?

Comment: Testing this locally (6 core i7 on macOS, Mac Mini) yields very consistent results for both 20s runs and 60s runs, both about ~140M/s. There's no slow down. It uses 100% of one core, as expected. The machine I'm using has good thermals and doesn't throttle with just one core pinned.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to understand what happens then at the system level.

Comment: I think you've inadvertently created a test for your hardware's cooling ability. Open up your case and blow out the dust. You'd be surprised how much that can interfere with performance. If the fan's choked out you'll have miserable throttling problems all the time.

Comment: I've just tested with OnlineGdb.com (with a Linux version of the source) and it is ok too there... You may be right. Thanks.

Comment: there is also one concern that that program may run out of counter's capacity. IF first value is correct, it will overflow in about 130 seconds (which, IMO, too slow for modern hardware)

Comment: Which variable in my program are you referring to ?

Comment: @KotlinIsland repeat counter , of course! Are you sure that your `long` isn't 32 bit? It usually is

Comment: It's an unsigned long and when I do CTRL+C then the "Number of effective repeats" is always ok, even after 8 hours of running :)

Comment: Sorry, I've checked on my Win10 machine and unsigned long max value is 4294967295 and on OnlineGbd (with linux version of my sourcecode), the max value is 18446744073709551615... Very interesting comment from you ! Thanks ! I'll investigate that !!

Comment: That's first problem I ran into by copying your code? Is that real code? Another problem is type mismatch between `time_point` and called `now()`, Anf argument signature mismatch on calling `signal`.It doesn't compile. For counter, I'd used int64_t type and

Comment: This source compiles on Windows (Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition)... Are you on Windows ? It is real code, for sure.

Comment: @KotlinIsland yes, though SYS2 compiler, not VS. `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` and `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` are different types

Comment: That compiled in VS2019 but I've just replaced steady_clock by high_resolution_clock everywhere in the code... (Still same problem of performance degradation -or calculation problem due to unsigned long max value-).

Comment: You were right on the unsigned long max value !!!! Here is my new source code that has checked that : https://pastebin.com/K3kESzGz So I will try to use "unsigned long long", and on Win10 max is 18446744073709551615 such as the "unsigned long" on OnlineGdb... Thanks ! :) :) :)

Comment: Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: op> MSVC has different conventions (compared to most other x64 compilers). The default size of `long` being one of the differences. It is correct though, as the C++ standard does not make guarantees on the max value of `long` (except it should be ≥ that of int). It's a good idea to get into the habit of checking the intended range whenever you go beyond a couple of 0s.

Comment: Thanks for these important reminders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by  integer overflow. `unsigned long` is at least 32 bit and on on some platforms it is equal to `unsigned int.`  `unsigned long long`  partially alleviates the issue, but technically the loop should have some kind of defense against that, albeit it adds to the cost of loop.

There are two problems with code portability, omitted by compiler due to implementation:

1. `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` should be `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`
2. `signal_callback_handler` should have return type `void`

Comment: I've just made another test (with the source code ok now) : After 2142.92s (t) the counter equals 353386274383 (a)... As unsigned long long (MSVC) is 18446744073709551615 (b) then I calculate b/a=52 199 944.96 (r) so it would take (r*t) seconds to reach the maximum (b) <=> 1 118 603 060 536 832 seconds so more than 35 470 670 years ;) If my calculations are right.

Comment: @KotlinIsland you'll still have 2036 year problem because system clock counts from a certain point in past and in nanoseconds :P

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: @KotlinIsland look up epoch time and "year 2038 problem". It's similar to  2000 year problem, though math is different

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did not know about that : Wow !